# Extract Multiline text from Excel cell- macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a multi column Excel which contain **a specific column** with Header 'NCT', it contains a multi-line repetitive text having following pattern

Student enrollment date=2004-03-21

Student code=NP/CPP

Student indicator=Neg

Student type=Under detention

Student details

Student state=MH MH4000001

Student date=2005-01-27

Student enrollment=21045-sd-554729

Student enrollment date=2004-05-01

Student code=NP/CPP

Student indicator=Pos

Student type=Under detention

Student details

Student state=MH MH4000001

Student date=2005-01-27

Student enrollment=21045-sd-554729

**Student enrollment date=2005-01-27**

**Student code=NP/CPP**

**Student indicator=Pos**

**Student type=Under detention**

**Student details**

**Student state=MH MH4000001**

**Student date=2005-01-27**

**Student enrollment=21045-sd-554729**

I wish to extract the most recent enrollment section from each ROW of NCT header, when extracted '**student enrollment date** ' is checked and most recent one is selected and entire following text till 'student enrollment' is copied to respective row of newly inserted column.

result I am looking for looks like below image

[image]

can anyone through some helping hand?

code working till now is

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x       As Variant
    Dim a()     As Variant
    Dim r       As Long
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim j       As Long

    For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        x = Split(Range("A" & r).Value, vbLf)
        For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
            If InStr(x(i), "=") Then
                ReDim Preserve a(j)
                a(UBound(a)) = Split(x(i), "=")(1)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
        Range("C" & r).Resize(, UBound(a) + 1).Value = a
        Erase x: Erase a: j = 0
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Split(cellContent, vbLf) to get the lines into an array, then loop over that to locate the date you need.  You can use split(line,"=") to extract the label and the value in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```html
Sub Test()
    Dim x       As Variant
    Dim y       As Variant
    Dim a()     As Variant
    Dim r       As Long
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim j       As Long
    
    For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        y = "Student enrollment date=" & SplitByLastOccurrence(Range("A" & r).Value, "Student enrollment date")(1)
        x = Split(y, vbLf)
        For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
            If InStr(x(i), "=") Then
                ReDim Preserve a(j)
                a(UBound(a)) = Split(x(i), "=")(1)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
        Range("C" & r).Resize(, UBound(a) + 1).Value = a
        Erase x: Erase a: j = 0
    Next r
End Sub

Function SplitByLastOccurrence(s As String, delimiter As String)
    Dim arr, i As Long
    
    If Len(s) = 0 Or Len(delimiter) = 0 Then
        SplitByLastOccurrence = CVErr(2001)
    Else
        i = InStrRev(s, delimiter)
        If i = 0 Then
            SplitByLastOccurrence = Array(s)
        Else
            ReDim arr(0 To 1)
            arr(0) = Trim(Left$(s, i - 1))
            arr(1) = Trim(Mid$(s, i + Len(delimiter) + 1))
            SplitByLastOccurrence = arr
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thanks but code run for entire content I am interested in last multiline section

Comment: As for inserting code, i was suffering and found the best option is HTML .. I don't know how to insert the code properly. Can any moderator guide me, please?

Comment: thanks yasser it does split the content in column but I need only BOLD last  content in question , your code splits all the cell value. to put short i need last bunch of line starting from Student enrollment date=2005-01-27

Comment: I have edited the code again. It is better to explain every detail from the very beginning
Try it now and inform me if everything is OK or not

Comment: hi Yasser I ran into a situation wherein order of prefix changes means 'Student type' can shift places in multiline text last bunch can we limit split by column Header? means if Column Header is 'Student Type' respective data of multiline text is pasted. do helpme out

Answer (score 0):

you may be after something like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim recentStudent As String
    Dim studentInfo As Variant

    For Each cell In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        recentStudent = Replace(GetMostRecentStudent(cell.Text), "Student details" & vbLf, "")
        cell.Offset(, 1) = recentStudent
        For Each studentInfo In Split(recentStudent, vbLf)
            cell.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Value = Split(studentInfo, "=")(1)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function GetMostRecentStudent2(cellTxt As String)
    GetMostRecentStudent = Right(cellTxt, Len(cellTxt) - InStrRev(cellTxt, "Student enrollment date") + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: thanks but it throws error at cell.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Value = Split(studentInfo, "=")(1) and getMostRecentStudent2

Comment: seems like you're already done. so no reason to go on here